# Shrink image on click

Tags: javascript, html, image, click

I would like to use JavaScript to shrink an image by 10% every time it is clicked and display a counter of how many times it has been clicked.

I've wired up the click event but am unsure where to go from there.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.click = function() {

  document.getElementById('knox').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.animalpicturesociety.com/modules/uploads/bo/boston-terrier1.jpg');
    e.target.appendChild(img);
  });

};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="knox" src="http://www.animalpicturesociety.com/modules/uploads/bo/boston-terrier1.jpg" alt="Boston Terrier" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How much smaller with each click? What do you consider *the end*?

Comment: The [JavaScript `onClick`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event should come in handy here.

Comment: What have you tried? If you run into problems while trying to implement this functionality, feel free to ask a question here. However, we aren't going to build the entire thing for you.

Comment: width and height attributes of an image could be also defined by percentage, so they could be modified with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the [onClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event to call a function which shrinks the image by 10% and displays the number of times the image has been shrank and by how much.

```js
var count = 0;

function shrink(img) {
    count++;
    var height = img.height * .1,
        result = document.getElementById("result");

    img.height -= height;
    result.innerHTML = "img shrank by " + height + "px -- clicked " + count + " times";
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/technics"/ onClick="shrink(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it after doing a lot more research and digging. I ended up restarting everything from scratch, this is the code I had as a result:

```
<doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Image Game </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var clickCount = 0;
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="knox" src="https://40.media.tumblr.com/218651d289309c8074b4a9aa3de8395c/tumblr_mvphoxIUXq1sd3xkpo1_250.png"  
            OnClick="clickCount = clickCount + 1; this.width -= 10; this.height -= 10;" onmousedown=""/>
<br>    
            <button 
                OnClick= "document.getElementById('countDisplay').innerHTML = clickCount;
                document.getElementById('knox').width += counter * 10;
                document.getElementById('knox').height += counter * 10;
                clickCount = 0;"> Clicks </button>

            <h1 id="countDisplay"></h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks everyone for the help!